# Usage of setInterval() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why beneath code is not working.

```
function doSome(){
    console.log("Hi");
}

setInterval(doSome(), '1000');
```

what I expected :

```
// every second
Hi
Hi
Hi
...
```

but result

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:275:18)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Okay, If I change `setInterval(doSome(), '1000');` to `setInterval(function(){doSome()}, '1000');` The code works finely. But I don't know what is different, and why I have to wrap the function like `function(){...}` Can you tell me some hints, Thanks...

Comment: `setInterval(doSome(), '1000');` ==> `setInterval(doSome, 1000);` when passing function as reference, use only function name. **Remove `()` of `doSome`, time should not be string**

Comment: Remove the parenthesis `()`.. you are invoking the function. You need to pass a reference, therefore it should be `setInterval(doSome, 1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is setInteval expects the first argument to be a reference to a function, while `doSome()` will evaluate to some value, in this case `null`.

What you want is the following:

```
function doSome(){
  console.log("hi");
}
setInterval(doSome, 1000);
```

As you noted, you could also use an anonymous function (which returns a reference to that function), that calls the function you really want to execute. This is useful for calling a function that takes parameters.

```
function doMore(x, y){
  if (x < y)
    console.log("Hi");
  else
    console.log("Bye");
}
setInterval(function(){ doMore(0,1);}, 1000);
```

The second example is trivial but shows how you can call functions that require parameters using `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use anonymous function ie. named function then you're calling it using the parentheses so remove it and will work fine:

```
setInterval(doSome, 1000);//You still don't need to wrap interval time within string
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `setInterval` requires a function as it's first argument.
The beauty of JavaScript is that you could even return a function from `doSome`:

```
function doSome(param){
    return function() { console.log(param); }
}

setInterval(doSome("Hi"), 1000);
```

But of course the correct answer is:

```
function doSome(){
    return console.log("Hi");
}

setInterval(doSome, 1000);
```